# Firefox displaying static gif. Works fine in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, firefox

Please help me.  I have spent good amount of time to fix this without any success. The following loading modal box works fine in all browsers except FireFox. In firefox it shows static gif image instead of animated loading spin.

Html:

```
 <input type="submit" name="SubmitPayment" value="Complete Order" class="square checkout button" onclick="ShowProgressAnimation();" /> 

<div id="loading-div-background">
<div id="loading-div" style="display:none"><img style="margin:30px;" src="images/loading.gif"   alt="Loading.."/>

<p align="center" valign="middle" style="color:##1a0980; font-size:24px; font-weight:normal; text-align:center">Please Wait While We Are Processing Your Order....</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Java Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loading-div-background ").css({ opacity: 0.8 });

    }); 

    function ShowProgressAnimation() {           

        $("#loading-div-background").show();
    var pb = document.getElementById("loading-div");
    pb.innerHTML = '<img style="margin:30px;" src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading.."/>'; 
    pb.style.display = '';  

    }


</script>
```

Css:

```
#loading-div-background 
{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    /* background:black; */
    background-color: #EDF1F4;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index: 10000;
 }

#loading-div
{
     width: 400px;
     height: 200px;
     background-color: #EDF1F4;
     text-align:center;
     position:absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     margin-left:-200px;
     margin-top: -100px;
 }
```

Comment: Odd random thing; try increasing the opacity to 100% and see if that does anything?

Comment: Could be the display: none initially that could make the animated gif not being triggered.

Comment: If I remove display:none from <div id="loading-div"> and following code from Java Script than it works fine in Firefox but then cause the same problem in internet explorer....

Comment: Otherwise set it to visibility hidden initially  and when loading  updating the src of the animated gif and set to visible?

Comment: Can you please paste as a code? I am new to learning java script. Thanks for your help in advance..

Comment: I have tried using visibility hidden and then pb.style.visibility = 'visible' but it still shows static image in firefox...